# AngularJs & UI Router - submodule is being registered before it's parent module?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui router to manage routing, including for for submodules.

Here's the directory structure for the parent and child:

admin
   |
   | ---buildteams
   |         |
   |         |--- buildteams.js
   |         |--- buildteams.tpl.html
   |--- admin.js
   |--- admin.tpl.html

admin.js looks like this:

```
(function(adminModule) {

adminModule.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'AdminController as vm',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/admin.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Administration' }})

        .state('admin.buildteams', {
            url: '/buildteams',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'AdminController as vm',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/admin.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Build Teams' }
        });
});

adminModule.controller('AdminController', function ($scope,
                                                                $modal,
                                                                $state) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.itemSelected = function(item){

        if(item)
        {
            vm.template = item.template;
            vm.selected = {};

            vm.selected[item.name] = true;
        }

    };

    var init = function(vm) {

        vm.menuItems = [
            {
                name: "Build Teams",
                href: "admin.buildteams",
                template: "admin/buildteams/buildteams.tpl.html"
            }
        ];

        var current = $state.current.name;
        var item = vm.menuItems.find(function(x){
            return x.href===current;
        });

        vm.itemSelected(item);
    };

    init(vm);



});}(angular.module("myApp.admin", ['ui.router'])));
```

buildteams.js looks like this:

```
(function(adminModule) {

adminModule.controller('AdminBuildTeamsController', function ($scope,$modal) {

    var vm = this;

    var init = function(vm) {



    };

    init(vm);

});}(angular.module("myApp.admin")));
```

Here's where I register the modules:

```
(function(app) {

//configure routing
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})

//inject http provider with authorization header
.config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
            function($q, cachedUserService) {
                return {
                    'request': function(config) {
                        //ditch if the url is not api
                        var user = cachedUserService.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user) {
                            config.headers["Authorization"] = user.token;
                        }
                        return config || $q.when(config);
                    }                        
                };
            }
        );
    }
);

//register directives
app.directive("verticalMenu", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "partialtemplates/verticalmenu.tpl.html"
    };
});

//not sure what this is
app.run(function () {});

//main controller
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope,
                                          cachedUserService,
                                          $modal,
                                          userAccountService,
                                          $location) {

    $scope.pageTitle = "myApp";

    $scope.user = cachedUserService.getCurrentUser();

    $scope.showLoginDialog = function()
    {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'loginDialogContent.html',
            controller: 'LoginDialogController',
            windowClass: 'app-modal-window'
        });

        $scope.loginDialogOpened = true;

        modalInstance.result.then(function (user) {

            $scope.user = user;
            cachedUserService.setRememberEmail($scope.user.email);

        }, function () {

        });
    };

    if($scope.user == null)
    {
        $scope.user = {
            loggedIn : false
        };
    }

    //app controller watches
    $scope.$watch('user', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(oldVal.loggedIn != newVal.loggedIn)
        {
            $scope.$broadcast('userLoggedIn', newVal);
        }
    });

    $scope.logout = function()
    {
        userAccountService.logout();
        $scope.user = {
            loggedIn : false
        };
        $location.path("/home");
    };

    $scope.unauthorizedNavigation = function(desiredPath)
    {
        $location.path("/home");
        $scope.showLoginDialog();
    };

    $scope.loginDialogOpened = false;

});}(angular.module("myApp", [
'myApp.home',
'myApp.about',
'myApp.useradmin',
'myApp.admin',
'templates-app',
'templates-common',
'ui.router.state',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap'
])));
```

When I try to build, I get this error:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.admin' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.admin
>     at /Users/richard/Projects/myAppFrontEnd/vendor/angular/angular.js:78
>   Firefox 35.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.272 secs / 0 secs)

I traced through it and discovered that angular is attempting to register the `buildteams` submodule **before** it registers the `admin` module. So the `admin` module is not there to add the `buildteams` submodule to.

One thing to note...this EXACT code is WORKING in another case in the same app. In fact this module/submodule code was copied from the useradmin files in the same project. (see the module registration above where I register `useradmin` and `admin`.

Any ideas? What's going on?

**In what order does angular load the modules? Is there any way to specify that order?**

**EDIT**

Here's the html for the parent module:

```
(function(adminModule) {

adminModule.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'AdminController as vm',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/admin.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Administration' }})

        .state('admin.buildteams', {
            url: '/buildteams',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'AdminController as vm',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/admin.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Build Teams' }
        });
});

adminModule.controller('AdminController', function ($scope,
                                                                            $modal,
                                                                            $state) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.itemSelected = function(item){

        if(item)
        {
            vm.template = item.template;
            vm.selected = {};

            vm.selected[item.name] = true;
        }

    };

    var init = function(vm) {

        vm.menuItems = [
            {
                name: "Build Teams",
                href: "admin.buildteams",
                template: "admin/buildteams/buildteams.tpl.html"
            }
        ];

        var current = $state.current.name;
        var item = vm.menuItems.find(function(x){
            return x.href===current;
        });

        vm.itemSelected(item);
    };

    init(vm);



});}(angular.module("myApp.admin", [
'ui.router'])));
```

Here's the html for the submodule:

```
<div ng-controller="AdminBuildTeamsController as sub">
     Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also show the html where you load the scripts?

Comment: What's strange is this exact code is working in the same project for another parent and it's sub modules.

Comment: It seems you were running this on Karma, are you sure you specified the admin module file to Karma? Angular always resolves dependencies in the sensible order, I don't think you can affect it.

Comment: Also, I might see another problem. I guess the form of angular.module without dependencies needs the module to be loaded at that moment in time. With html, you would fix this by re-organizing the script elements so that the module creation is first. With karma, you have to specify the creating file first in the list of files that karma should load.

Comment: Thanks. I am running Karma. But the error happens in the app too. If I load the parent view, it gives me that error and I can see it's loading the submodule first.

Comment: I haven't specified any modules to karma. I haven't done that for any of the modules and they work.

Comment: But you have to specify the files that karma should load. Otherwise karma would be doing nothing. Perhaps you are using a glob pattern like admin/**/*.js to grab all files?

Comment: yeah it's a blob - files: [
            <% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>'<%= file %>',
                <% }); %>
            'src/**/*.js',
      'src/**/*.coffee',
    ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70940/discussion-between-juunas-and-richard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per our chat discussion, the problem was in the order that the browser / karma is loading the files. Grunt was used to find all the .js files, and it would try to parse the submodule file first because the folder name was alphabetically before the main .js file.

So running

```
angular.module("myApp.admin")
```

before

```
angular.module("myApp.admin", [])
```

caused the issue. Grunt was setup to load all the js files but loaded them in the wrong order. A solution was to rename the files such that the ordering is right.